# Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester

Tags: jsf, websphere-9

After starting Websphere 9 server, I am getting an exception. Below mentioned exception stack trace.

```
 E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.<init>(DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.java:42)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.getUnmarshaller(DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.java:93)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.getStandardFacesConfig(DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.java:135)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.getFacesConfigData(DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.java:69)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:416)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:370)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:143)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1836)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:442)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:8
```

Can anyone help to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have all the dependencies of MyFaces and their corresponding versions.

http://myfaces.apache.org/core22/dependency-management.html

The last versions use commons-digester version 1.8.

It could also be a classloader issue, maybe this link helps [WAS 8.5.5 & MyFaces 2.1 Shared library](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=6eaab321-76d4-42ab-8ae6-e366994448f4)

Comment: Earlier application run in tomcat successfully with below jars

Comment: Earlier application run in tomcat successfully with below jars                    
commons-beanutils-1.9.0.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-digester-1.8
commons-lang-2.6
commons-logging-1.1
commons-pool-1.5.4
commons-dbcp-1.4
myfaces-api-2.1.10
myfaces-impl-2.1.10
primefaces-4.0
But After migrating to websphere 9 only application throws exception

Comment: Then it seems to be an issue with the classloading in Websphere, i have very little experience with WAS but maybe this can help you: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=6eaab321-76d4-42ab-8ae6-e366994448f4

Comment: these jars commons-digester-1.8, commons-logging-1.1,commons-beanutils-1.9.0.jar, commons-codec-1.3.jar,myfaces-api-2.1.10 ,myfaces-impl-2.1.10 placed in shared lib. then this resolved

Comment: Thanks for letting me know how it went, i am glad it helped.